# Format cells with the same values split by a delimiter, but a different order in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am a VBA beginner, who cannot seem to find a solution to what seemed to be a very easy comparison to me at first.

Basically, I have 2 columns where the values in the cells are split by a delimiter, however, not in the same order.

eg.

```
Range("A1").value = "1234|5678"

Range("B1").value = "5678|1234"
```

B1 should then be highlighted as a duplicate

I am searching for some vba code which I can use to loop through the used range's in Columns A & B, to compare and highlight cells in column B that are duplicated, as per example above.

Apologies if I missed any similar questions asked and answered previously, I have indeed conducted a search but perhaps my search criteria may have been out of bounds, and I simply did not come across the VBA solution.

Regards,
Enjay

Comment: Would you share the code you already have? If you already can compare "componentwise"/in order, then I'd suggest to just add two inner loops to "cross-check" each sub-value of the first field against every sub-value of the second one.

Comment: Do these values only ever have one delimiter?

Comment: If it is only two items, then conditional formatting will do this, it is a long formula, but can be done without vba.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the little information given you could try the following code

```
Sub Highlight()

Const DELIMITER = "|"
Dim rg As Range
Dim a As Variant
Dim b As Variant
Dim sngCell As Range

    Set rg = Range("A1:A3")
    For Each sngCell In rg

        a = Split(sngCell.Value2, DELIMITER)
        b = Split(sngCell.Offset(, 1).Value2, DELIMITER)

        If isEqual(a, b) Then
            With sngCell.Offset(, 1).Interior
                .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
            End With
        End If
    Next sngCell

End Sub
```

with the following functions

```
Function isEqual(a As Variant, b As Variant) As Boolean

    a = BubbleSort(a)
    b = BubbleSort(b)

    isEqual = True

    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
        If a(i) <> b(i) Then
            isEqual = False
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i

End Function

Function BubbleSort(ByRef strArray As Variant) As Variant
    'sortieren von String Array
    'eindimensionale Array
    'Bubble-Sortier-Verfahren
   Dim z       As Long
   Dim i       As Long
   Dim strWert As Variant

    For z = UBound(strArray) - 1 To LBound(strArray) Step -1
        For i = LBound(strArray) To z
            If LCase(strArray(i)) > LCase(strArray(i + 1)) Then
                strWert = strArray(i)
                strArray(i) = strArray(i + 1)
                strArray(i + 1) = strWert
            End If
        Next i
    Next z

    BubbleSort = strArray

End Function
```

Comment: This worked perfectly as a solution as well :) Thank you and much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This will answer your question as-is. If the solution needs to be adjusted, I trust that you can fix it :)

This uses `StrComp` to (in memory only) re-order the two string parts so that it can easily detect duplicate values.

```
Option Explicit

Sub DuplicateCheck()

    Dim delimiter As String
    delimiter = "|"

    Dim lastCol As Long
    lastCol = Cells(1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To lastCol
        Dim theSplit As Variant
        theSplit = Split(Cells(1, i), delimiter)

        Dim temp As String

        If StrComp(theSplit(0), theSplit(1), vbTextCompare) = 1 Then
            temp = theSplit(1)
            theSplit(1) = theSplit(0)
            theSplit(0) = temp
        End If

        temp = theSplit(0) & delimiter & theSplit(1)

        If Not dict.exists(temp) Then
            dict.Add (temp), 1
        Else
            Cells(1, i).Interior.color = 65535
        End If

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, this will definitely work as a solution, and I will adjust it accordingly :) I appreciate your time and effort.

Comment: Nice use of StrComp to make keys comparable +1). Just in case it's wanted to process code again after a possible change of cells in row 1, I'd recommend to state a `ws.Range("1:1").Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone` before the `For`-`Next` loop to clear all current formats. - *Side note for @Enjay: I'd always prefer fully qualified range references, so one should declare and set a worksheet object (e.g. `Dim ws As Worksheet` and `Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Marcucci")`) and use it as prefix like `ws.Cells(1, i).Interior.Color` or `ws.Cells(...)*.

Comment: @T.M. Thanks fam. At some point while I was putting this together I had set it up to undo the coloring, not sure why I removed it! Storax's answer ends up solving every case, though, since it can take strings with more than one delimiter